# Optimize the code when creating new columns based on the number of token of the row

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

Is there any way to optimize the following code?

```py
c1_arr = F.col('col1')
c2_arr = F.split('col2', ' ')
arr_of_struct = F.transform(
    c1_arr,
    lambda x: F.struct(
        F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(x, ' '))).alias('cnt'),
        x.alias('val'),
    )
)
top_val = F.sort_array(arr_of_struct, False)[0]


df = df.withColumn('match', F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 1)&(F.size(F.split(F.col('col2'), ' '))>1), top_val['val']))

df = df.withColumn('match_one_token', F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 0 )&(F.size(F.split(F.col('col2'), ' '))==1), top_val['val']))
```

The `arr_of_struct` makes each row of `col1` a list with separating by `','` .

**1st part**

The following code selects an element of `col2` where is has the most common token with tokens of `col1` (the intersection is larger than 1 and the size of the element of `col2` is larger than one).

```py
df = df.withColumn('match', F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 1)&(F.size(F.split(F.col('col2'), ' '))>1), top_val['val']))
```

**2nd part**

The following code selects an element of `col2` where is has a common token with tokens of `col1` (the intersection is equal 1 and the size of the element of `col2` is equal one).

```py
df = df.withColumn('match_one_token', F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 0 )&(F.size(F.split(F.col('col2'), ' '))==1), top_val['val']))
```

Example:

```
key     col1                                                         col2
ab    'summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go'      "let be hot"
cd     'do it better', 'I am sa'                                     "I need to go"
fg      'my best post, fun sunday'                                   "it's great"
```

Output:

```
key     col1                                                         col2            match     match_one_token
ab    'summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go'    "let be hot"    "let it go"  NA
cd     'do it better, I am sa'                                  "I need it do sa"    "I am sa"  NA
fg      'my best post, fun sunday'                                    "it's great"       NA   NA
gh        'my best, lets go'                                           'best'           NA       'best'
```

The first row has a common token with both `summer hot` and `let it go`, but it doesn't matter which one is selected.

The problem is that the 1st part is fast enough but when I do the 2nd part it takes a lot of time.

Comment: The input does not match output! **Please test your code** before uploading. **1.** There are 3 lines in input, but 4 lines on output. **2.** The bottom right corner in output should probably be 'my best' instead of 'best'. **3.** `c1_arr = F.col('col1')` should probably be `c2_arr = F.split('col2', ' ')`, based on another question that I have answered, otherwise this code returns an error! **4.** 'let it go' cannot be returned in the first line of 'match' column, because it does not have >1 common tokens. PLEASE test what you post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following. I've changed something in several parts of the code, so I hope this will work.

1. Minor thing which you may not even need - knowing the history of this question, I've changed `c1_arr` and `c2_arr` (now the code in this question can at least run).

   ```py
   c1_arr = F.split('col1', ',\s*')
   c2_arr = F.split('col2', '\s+')
   ```
2. The main change which may boost the performance slightly is removing `withColumn` and using `select`.
   So, instead of

   ```py
   df = df.withColumn('match', F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 1)&(F.size(F.split(F.col('col2'), ' '))>1), top_val['val']))
   df = df.withColumn('match_one_token', F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 0 )&(F.size(F.split(F.col('col2'), ' '))==1), top_val['val']))
   ```

   you could use

   ```py
   df = df.select(
       '*',
       F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 1) & (F.size(c2_arr) > 1), top_val['val']).alias('match'),
       F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 0) & (F.size(c2_arr) == 1), top_val['val']).alias('match_one_token')
   )
   ```

**Full code**

- Modified input dataframe:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [('ab', 'summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go', "let go hot"),
       ('cd', 'do it better, I am sa', "I need to do sa"),
       ('fg', 'my best post, fun sunday', "it's great"),
       ('gh', 'my best, lets go', "best")],
      ['key', 'col1', 'col2'])
  df.show(truncate=0)
  # +---+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
  # |key|col1                                                   |col2           |
  # +---+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
  # |ab |summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go|let go hot     |
  # |cd |do it better, I am sa                                  |I need to do sa|
  # |fg |my best post, fun sunday                               |it's great     |
  # |gh |my best, lets go                                       |best           |
  # +---+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
  ```
- Script:

  ```py
  c1_arr = F.split('col1', ',\s*')
  c2_arr = F.split('col2', '\s+')
  arr_of_struct = F.transform(
      c1_arr,
      lambda x: F.struct(
          F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(x, ' '))).alias('cnt'),
          x.alias('val'),
      )
  )
  top_val = F.sort_array(arr_of_struct, False)[0]

  df = df.select(
      '*',
      F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 1) & (F.size(c2_arr) > 1), top_val['val']).alias('match'),
      F.when((top_val['cnt'] > 0) & (F.size(c2_arr) == 1), top_val['val']).alias('match_one_token')
  )

  df.show(truncate=0)
  # +---+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------------+
  # |key|col1                                                   |col2           |match    |match_one_token|
  # +---+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------------+
  # |ab |summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go|let go hot     |let it go|null           |
  # |cd |do it better, I am sa                                  |I need to do sa|I am sa  |null           |
  # |fg |my best post, fun sunday                               |it's great     |null     |null           |
  # |gh |my best, lets go                                       |best           |null     |my best        |
  # +---+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------------+
  ```